# probability of k occurrence in sequence vs probability of k occurrence in n trials

Tags: probability

I am building a puzzle game like bejewelled. My rows are 4 long horizontally and I am randomly generating 5 color gems (Red,Blue,Green,Yellow,Orange) with uniform probability.

I wanted to compare the probability of no red gem twice in **sequence** in 3 picks and the probability of not picking a red gem twice in 3 picks.  For the sequence probability, I used conditional probability with recursive method

$P_i$ - probability of no 2 red gems in sequence

$i=1$

$P_1 = 1$

$i=2$

no 2 red sequence with 2 picks: $\{OO,OR,RO,RR\}$

$P_2 = 0.8^2 + 0.8\cdot 0.2 + 0.2\cdot 0.8 = 0.96$

for $i \geq  3 $

$$ P_i = P(no red | red)*P(red)     + P(no red| no red)* P(no red) \\= [P_{i-2} * P(no red)] * P(red) + P_{i-1}* P(no red) $$

P_3 = 1 * 0.8 * 0.2 + 0.96 * 0.8  = 0.928

Then I found the probability of having 2 reds show up in general:

note:foregoing the combination process to get 3

$P(2\text{ red in }3\text{ picks}) + P(3\text{ red in }3\text{ picks})  = 3 \cdot 0.2^2 \cdot 0.8 ^1 + 1*0.2^3*.8^0  = 0.096 + 0.008$

$P(\text{no }2\text{ red in }3\text{ picks}) = 0.896$

My question is, is my methodology in finding this correct? It seems reasonable that the probability of a strictly less than 2 red sequence is < the probability of picking more than or equally to 2 reds in 3 picks.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "no two reds in sequence" method is correct, but your second calculation is the probability of not picking *exactly* two reds out of three, so you need to subtract the probability of all three gems being red ($0.008$), and get $0.896$.

As a check, the difference between the two should be the cases where you have two reds, but not two in a row, i.e. the probability of (in order) red-other-red, which is $0.2\times0.8\times0.2=0.032$, and this is indeed equal to $0.928-0.896$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my double count! Further, can i conclude then, if i were to generate 3 of any color gems with uniform probability that there is a (1-0.928)*5 chance that a color will have 2 in sequence gems?

Comment: Yes. If there are two consecutive gems of the same colour out of three, then there is exactly one colour with two consecutive, so you can just add up the $0.072$ chance for each colour.

Comment: But if you were looking for two consecutive of the same colour out of four, it wouldn't just be $5\times(1- P_4)$, because that would double-count e.g. red-red-green-green.

Comment: @ Especially Lime I think you are incorrect with the second part of the assertion.  I am using the Binomial formula which accounts for duplicates, I have updated my answer to verify this. Please comment

Comment: As I said, it depends whether you want the probability of having *exactly two* of the three gems red (which is $0.096$) or the probability of having *two or more* gems red (which is $0.096+0.008$). The binomial formula $\binom nrp^r(1-p)^{n-r}$ gives the probability of getting exactly $r$ out of $n$, so if you want "at least $r$" you need to add up all the terms from $r$ up to $n$.

Comment: But in the other part of your question you've correctly calculated the probability of having at *two or more* consecutive reds ($0.072=1-0.928$). So I assumed "two or more" is what you are interested in.

Comment: Ah you are correct, i have to remove the more then 3 results from my recursion. Is there a general way to remove the > 3 results? Say I wanted to run this for i=4, what would what I remove ?